# Can I add reference from .NET 7.0 project to a class library in .NET Framework 4.7.2 and deploy it?

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version, .net-7.0

I've a .NET 7.0 project and I've added a reference to class library in .NET Framework 4.7.2. It is running fine in my local. But while deploying it is giving this error:

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1229,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

It will be great if someone could help me on this error. Thanks in advance!

I was trying to deploy the project and it was throwing an error.

Comment: This is not a supported scenario; there is a hard break between netfx (.net framework 4.7.2 etc) and "current" .net (.net core, .net 6, .net 7 etc); referencing in either direction *except for* via netstandard2.0: is not supported; the class library you're trying to reference: any chance you can update it to .net 7?

Comment: The classLibrary is in .NET Framework. And I've already created some helper classes there which is not supported by .NET Class Library. So is there any way by which I can use this referencing and deploy it.

Comment: again: no, this is not a supported scenario; what specific .net framework features are you using that is forcing you to use .net framework?

Comment: I'm using .NET 7.0 for creating web api's

Comment: yes, but I asked about the .net framework part; what is making you use *that* instead of .net 7?

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I migrated every projects to .NET 6.0